# Angular JS for game UI

Tags: html, user-interface, angularjs, game-engine, impactjs

I am currently building a web game using html5 and the Impact JS game engine.  I want to overlay html components over the top of the canvas/impact engine, and I was looking for some frameworks that would help with ui/dependency injection/databinding etc.

So I found angular js, and was so happy to see such a wonderful framework until after a few days of research I encounter this little snippet in their [developer guides](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/overview).

"Games, and GUI editors are examples of very intensive and tricky DOM manipulation. These kinds of apps are different from CRUD apps, and as a result are not a good fit for Angular. In these cases using something closer to bare metal such as jQuery may be a better fit."

This was somewhat upsetting, partly because I cant seem to find any specifics about this statement.  If I am trying to use angular for rendering/looping a game engine, then yea its probably not going to be great, but surely it should be fine as just a UI layer?

Is there anyone out there with experience in this area, there are some tricky UI things that I need to do that would take a lot longer I believe without using something like Angular JS.

Comment: The question probably is, are you going to create your own UI elements or are you planning on re-using html elements like input and button etc.. If its the latter then yes, angular will work.. but say you build a complete UI ( look and feel ) by building them up from images etc.. Then probably angular is not a good fit.

Comment: had planned on using just divs and background images with hover/click events, and some rpg style menus with inventory management and the like.

Answer (score 2):

There's a plugin to to overlay UI elements

[Overlays](http://www.pointofimpactjs.com/plugins/view/38/overlays-menu-hud-ui-etc)